# matlab changed my linux application's environment variables

Tags: matlab, environment-variables

I am trying to run an application called mf2k from MATLAB shell. In Bash shell, this command reads:

```
    $ ldd mf2k.mac               linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff807d6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4e3c32d000)
    libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f4e3c017000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4e3bd16000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4e3bb00000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f4e3b8ca000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4e3c6d4000)
```

However, once I execute the same command in matlab shell, it returns

```
>> !ldd mf2k.mac
./mf2k.mac: /home/chenming/SLhome/chenming/apps/Matlab2012b/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by ./mf2k.mac)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffd637f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2e226aa000)
    libgfortran.so.3 => /home/chenming/SLhome/chenming/apps/Matlab2012b/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f2e223bf000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2e220be000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/chenming/SLhome/chenming/apps/Matlab2012b/sys/os/glnxa64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2e21ea8000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f2e21c72000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2e22a51000)
```

note that the path for libgfortran.so.3 and libgcc_s.so.1 has been changed.

How can I set the environmental variable right in MATLAB schell? I found this question is related [question](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFcQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F8340818%2Fstart-application-from-matlab&ei=sY8uVJL5J5CA8gX0l4GICg&usg=AFQjCNGiPQhesF0hg7IU55ZGhW8ZUztiDw&sig2=K8uyzumYnnQzJwCrlaX6lg&bvm=bv.76802529,d.dGc), but their solution does not apply here.

-----------------------update ---------------------------------

here are the **$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH** ran in bash shell and matlab shell.

In bash shell:

```
 $ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mkl/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/debugger/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mpirt/lib/intel64
```

In Matlab shell:

```
>> ! echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/chenming/SLhome/chenming/apps/Matlab2012b/sys/os/glnxa64:/home/chenming/SLhome/chenming/apps/Matlab2012b/bin/glnxa64:/home/chenming/SLhome/chenming/apps/Matlab2012b/extern/lib/glnxa64:/home/chenming/SLhome/chenming/apps/Matlab2012b/runtime/glnxa64:/home/chenming/SLhome/chenming/apps/Matlab2012b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/home/chenming/SLhome/chenming/apps/Matlab2012b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/home/chenming/SLhome/chenming/apps/Matlab2012b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mkl/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/debugger/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mpirt/lib/intel64
```

Answer (score 0):

whats in your bashrc? Check your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your bashrc. In your LD library path matlab must be before system variables. $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is usually set in .bashrc or .bash_profile if you are using bash or .cshrc if you shell is csh. The command

```
    echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

will print your path and

```
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libdir/you/want/to add:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

will change the order.

EDIT:
What does your application mf2k do? I am assuming it is a FORTRAN program that you have compiled and linked to the gfortran library and it does not run inside the matlab shell. Can you statically compile mf2k so that it does not need libraries at run time. Also you can try to execute the following shell script inside matlab:

```
    !#/bin/bash
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mkl/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/debugger/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/mpirt/lib/intel64
    ./mf2k
```

Answer (score 0):

Matlab adds its own libraries to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you cannot change that as it will most likely break the matlab application if you force it to use your system's libraries.

What you can do is set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from within Matlab before calling your application using [`setenv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setenv.html), as described in the question you linked to. I don't see how it doesn't apply in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Just run command in **MATLAB**:

> > setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH',[getenv('PATH') getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')])

It appends matlab library in system library.